# Glance App widget in Jetpack compose take delay of widget when app is closed

Tags: android, widget, android-jetpack-compose, glance

```
class ClickActionCallback : ActionCallback {
    override suspend fun onAction(
        context: Context,
        glanceId: GlanceId,
        parameters: ActionParameters,
    ) {
        with(parameters) {
            val serverId = this[FactWidget.factPosition]
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val actionIntent = Intent(context, FactActivity::class.java)
                actionIntent.putExtra(Constants.SERVER_ID, serverId)
                actionIntent.putExtra(Constants.STORED_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis())
                actionIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                context.startActivity(actionIntent)
            }
        }
    }}
```

When app is not in background tap on widget app is not open directly.
If anyone know give me solution for above problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clickable modifier on your parent composable.

```
     val intent = Intent(LocalContext.current,HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
        setAction("fdo")
        putExtra(Constants.WIDGET,"widget")
     }


    Box(
        modifier = GlanceModifier
            .cornerRadius(20.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .clickable(
                androidx.glance.appwidget.action.actionStartActivity(
                intent
            ))
    )
```

Comment: Now i want to only perform some code not open any activity, than what should i do because when i add actionstartactivity in is work proper. but when i want to click on widget and add widget content into my favorite list than its take delay.

Comment: my code is..

@Composable
    private fun getActionCallbackFavorite(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int): Action {
        val intent = Intent(context, MyAppWidgetReceiver::class.java).apply {
            action = Constants.ACTION_WIDGET_FAVORITE
            putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId)
            putExtra("serverId", currentState(key = intPreferencesKey("current_fact_id_$appWidgetId")) ?: -1)
        }
        return actionSendBroadcast(intent)
    }